Raman transition probability for off-resonant light
I have a 3-level system, with the levels being $g_1$, $g_2$ and $e$ and their energies $E_1$, $E_2$, $E_e$ such that $|E_2-E_1|\ll|E_e-E_1|$ ($g_1$ and $g_2$ can even be degenerate, but in general they have a very small energy difference). The excited state has a decay rate $\Gamma$, with equal probability of decaying to either of the 2 ground states. I initially populate the $g_1$ state and drive an electric dipole allowed transition between $g_1$ and $e$ in the low saturation regime, with a Rabi frequency $\Omega$ and with $\Delta \gg \Gamma$, where $\Delta$ is the detuning between the laser and $E_e-E_1$. Normally, in this regime, I mainly have Rayleigh scattering i.e. the excited state doesn't get populated and the atom can be treated as a harmonic oscillator such that the electronic cloud oscillates and radiates light at the frequency of the driving transition, call it $\omega_l$. However, there is a small probability for the atom to end up in the $g_2$ state (we can assume that the laser can't excite $g_2$ to $e$, for example due to angular momentum selection rules, so once the atom ends up in $g_2$ everything stops), i.e. undergo a Raman scattering. How can I calculate the probability for this to happen?
